# How to create a slider like on the GoWeather weather app?

Tags: android, slider

The go weather app ([Go Weather On Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mediawoz.goweather&hl=en)) has a nice little slider near the bottom just above the "MON", "TUE", "WED" in the image below.

[image]

You can drag the slider Up to show a longer daily forecast in addition to the 3 days shown. You can also drag the slider down to close the slider and hide the daily graphical temperatures + icons.

I assume this is not a normal slider since it seems to support 3 positions

1. 90% of the screen (visible with forecast)
2. 20% of the screen (as below)
3. 0% of the screen (not visible except the slider bar)

Does anyone know how to make this type of UI?

Really appreciate a code sample or link to sites.

Answer (score 2):

This is just an arrangement of layouts and widgets, 
here is the sample xml I created, you can put diff widgets and layouts to design like this,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />


<SlidingDrawer android:id="@+id/SlidingDrawer" android:handle="@+id/slideHandleButton"
        android:content="@+id/contentLayout" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="120dp" android:orientation="vertical"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        >

         <Button 
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="10dp" 
             android:id="@+id/slideHandleButton"
             android:background="#00868B" />


         <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="150dp"
             android:background="#90000000"
             android:gravity="center|top"
              >

             <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                 >

                 <LinearLayout 
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                     >
                 <ImageView

                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/diego"

                     />
                 <Button

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Diego"

                     />
                 </LinearLayout>
             </FrameLayout>
             <FrameLayout
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1" 
                 >
                <LinearLayout 
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                     >
                 <ImageView

                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/ellie"

                     />
                 <Button

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Ellie"

                     />
                 </LinearLayout>
             </FrameLayout>
            <FrameLayout
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1" 
                 >
                 <LinearLayout 
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                     >
                 <ImageView

                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/scart"

                     />
                 <Button

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/sid"

                     />
                 </LinearLayout>
             </FrameLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

</SlidingDrawer>
```

Just paste this in your program, you will see the working data. No need to write code for now, You can handle related events base on your needs. Here I used images from site, so download some images or use your existing images and replace the drawable used in this code.
Hope you will get this.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the sample - but I think it is not quite what I am after. Technically I am after a 3 position drawer. Fully Open, partly Open, Closed.

Can a drawer be partly open? or is this something where one would have to create a new control from scratch to support this functionality?

Comment: ya, you can create drawer like tat. You have to design 2 Drawers at a time. One handle will open your first drawer and that opened drawer will be handle of your next drawer. You have to pass drawer's Layout id in 2nd drawer's handle.